# link_stat error: rsync can't find /home/user/ssh?

Tags: rsync

I have a bit of a strange error message on rsync.

I try to start rsync to run in the background"

`rsync -az ssh /home/user/folder user@server.example.com:/home/user/folder.backup &`

Then rsync gives the error message:

`rsync: link_stat "/home/user/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

I am using ssh-keys for the connection to the remote server.example.com.

Still I don't see how /home/user/ssh is connected to my rsync job.

Does someone know what the reason could be?

Greetings, Chris

Comment: is your username really `user`? The folder is normally `.ssh` not `ssh`.

Comment: `~/.ssh` is the default location of a user's keys. The ssh key is needed since rsync connects to a remote host and needs to authentify.

Comment: no, my username is not really user and my server domain is not really server.example.com ;-)

Comment: I am aware that the ssh keys are in ~./ssh. But I don't understand why the error message comes up.. Why is rsync complaining like it is?

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaaah!!! I see it now. 
I have the "ssh" still in (coming from an older rsync command template). That is totally unnecessary. 
The command should be

`rsync -az /home/user/folder user@server.example.com:/home/user/folder.backup &`

without the "ssh"...

Sorry to bother you,

Chris

(p.s. I edited some wrong words in my answer)